# Find & Replace forcing Scientific Notation format

Tags: excel, vba

I would like Excel to stop substituting a perfectly fine string that contains an E with its scientific notation equivalent when doing a Find & Replace with VBA.

I have tried forcing it by using `ReplaceFormat.NumberFormat = "@"` to no avail.

This is the code that illustrates my problem:

```
Sub testsub()

ActiveSheet.Columns("A:A").NumberFormat = "@"

fnd = "2"
rplc = "39456E10"

Range("A1").Value = fnd
Range("A2").Value = rplc

Application.ReplaceFormat.NumberFormat = "@"

  ActiveSheet.Cells.Replace what:=fnd, Replacement:=rplc, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
    SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=True
End Sub
```

And this is the outcome

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well depending on how many cells you got in your `Range` object. You could opt for a `Application.Substitute` method.

I think as long as you use a method/function that explicitly returns a `String` data type, you'll be good. Since `Substitute` does exactly that you could try something like below:

```
Sub Test
    Range("A1:A2").Value = Application.Substitute(Range("A1:A2"), "2", "39456E10")
End Sub
```

Working on the assumption your `Range` is already formatted as `"@"`. If not, you might want to include that in the code. This would also work for a larger-scale 2D-array, e.g.: `A1:Z1000`.

For example:

[image] > [image]

---

I figured the same applies for example `RegEx.Replace` method and the `Replace` function (not mistaken with the `Replace` method) for example. Which instead of the above would need iteration.

---

Just a fun fact, with `Application.Substitute` we could also tell `VBA` which occurence of our searchvalue we would like to replace. For example to only replace the 2nd occurence of the number `2`:

[image]

```
Range("A1:A4") = Application.Substitute(Range("A1:A4"), "2", "39456E10", 2)
```

[image]

---

However, as per @Pᴇʜ his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59789362/9758194), the apostrophe is there for a reason... =). Therefor, that would be my personal preference (and should be faster).

Comment: Nice, I didn't think of substitute.

Answer (score 3):

Just put an apostrophe `'` infront of your string to ensure it is considered as string when replacing:

```
rplc = "'39456E10"
```

The apostrophe won't show in the Excel cell.

Comment: Yes, of course this works.
I was wondering if this was the expected behavior of the find and replace or if there was a more elegant way to do this.

Comment: @user1627466 I guess this is the only way. The `'` is actually for such cases. Excel always tries to interpret data and choose a good format automatically. But I agree the behavior of the replace method is not what I would expect after setting number format to text.